# Unmarshallizing XML Java JAXB

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb

**XML is**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><products>
<product>

    <imagesurl>
    <imageurl><![CDATA[http://...]]></imageurl>
    <imageurl><![CDATA[http://...]]></imageurl>
    </imagesurl>

</product>
</products>
```

Then i have 3 classes to parse `XML`:

The `main` is:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "products")
public class XmlModelRoot {

    private ArrayList<ProductModel> productModels;

    public ArrayList<ProductModel> getProductModels() {
        return productModels;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "product")
    public void setProductModels(ArrayList<ProductModel> productModels) {
        this.productModels = productModels;
    }


}
```

The `Product class` is:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "product")
public class ProductModel {
private ArrayList<ImageUrlModel> imagesUrlModels;
public ArrayList<ImageUrlModel> getImagesUrlModels() {
        return imagesUrlModels;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "imagesurl")
    public void setImagesUrlModels(ArrayList<ImageUrlModel> imagesUrlModels) {
        this.imagesUrlModels = imagesUrlModels;
    }
}
```

And finaly i have Class for **list of URLs**:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "imagesurl")
public class ImageUrlModel {

    private String imageurl;

    public String getImageurl() {
        return imageurl;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "imagurl")
    public void setImageurl(String imageurl) {
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
    }
}
```

My issue is, that i should receive `ArrayList<ImageUrlModel>` with at last 2 urls, but no matter how many imageurl tags i have, the size of `ArrayList<ImageUrlModel>` list is only 1 and there is only last tag accessible.

What should i change to have all imageurl in `ArrayList<ImageUrlModel>`, to in this case  `ImageUrlModel.size()` should be `2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can redesign your `ProductModel` POJO to the below class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ProductModel {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="imagesurl")
    @XmlElement(name = "imageurl")
    private ArrayList<String> imageurl;

    public ArrayList<String> getImagesUrlModels() {
        return imageurl;
    }

    public void setImagesUrlModels(ArrayList<String> imagesUrlModels) {
        this.imageurl = imagesUrlModels;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "product")
public class ProductModel {
private ArrayList<ImageUrlModel> imagesUrlModels;
public ArrayList<ImageUrlModel> getImagesUrlModels() {
        return imagesUrlModels;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "imagesurl")
    @XmlElement(name = "imageurl")
    public void setImagesUrlModels(ArrayList<ImageUrlModel> imagesUrlModels) {
        this.imagesUrlModels = imagesUrlModels;
    }
}

public class ImageUrlModel {

    private String value;


    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    @XmlValue
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```